# Fractional scaling problem - it is half now

Tags: settings

I have a weird behavior. In my fresh installed ubuntu 20.04, I activated fractional scaling and set it to 125%. So far so good. Then, I changed back: deactivate fractional scaling and set it to 100%. But know, everything is so tiny, it seems to be 50% now. If I change to 200% it is like normal (100%), if I change to 100% it is like 50%...what should I do?